# Career in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to learn SharePoint. Are there any jobs for SharePoint professionals in this recession time? I have .NET knowledge.

Answer (score 10):

To say there is a demand for SharePoint would be an understatement.  Because prior to 2007 SP developers were very few and far between, there are precious few people out there that as of now have enough SP experience to work on the really complex projects.

However, SharePoint is not going away, and will be growing even further with the release of MSSPS 2010 next year.  If you're a good ASP.Net developer looking to find a niche, then SharePoint would be a good way to go.

My #1 tip for new SharePoint developers: Download the WSPBuilder Visual Studio add-on, and install it before you start any custom SharePoint work.  By seeing how the add-on structures your projects and adds SharePoint capital-F Features to SP Solution Packages, it will make it a LOT easier for those concepts to click in your head.

My #2 tip: [Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201) - the best book, hands down, to really explain how SharePoint works, top to bottom.  Read this cover to cover, and you'll know more than at least 30% of the SharePoint people out there.

Comment: Liked the reference to Inside MS WSS 3.0 book, but I moved beyond WSPBuilder to STSDEV and now on Visual Studio Extensions for WSS (VSeWSS) version 1.3.  It requires Visual Studio 2008, but is closer to what will come with the next version of Visual Studio and seems to integrate better than the other tools as well.

Comment: I didn't like the VSSeWSS extension for one reason - it autogenerates the solution XML, including the GUID, and that isn't in VSS.  So, if a new developer gets the code from VSS, makes an update, and tried to run upgradesolution on the WSP - it fails, because the GUID is different!

WSPBuilder includes the solution guid in a text file as part of the project, so when it generates the WSP, the same GUID is used every time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the autogeneration of the solution XML and GUID.  I'll take that into account.

Comment: Greg, can you provide more details?  VSeWSS1.3 has a pkg directory with a solution.xml file and manifest.xml file.  They both have the solution Id Guid in there.  It seems that this could be stored in source control.  Are you saying that it ignores the values in those files and just regenerates the Guid every time?

Comment: I may be working with old knowledge, but if I remember, the VSeWSS add-in doesn't automatically add the solution and manifest files to the project.  So, even if you add them manually, you will need to remember to manually check those files in & out of VSS with every change.  Inevitably (in my experience), there will be a developer that forgets, which leads to the headaches I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say two sites are worth checking:

1. MS SharePoint Developer: http://mssharepointdeveloper.com
2. My RampUp: http://myrampup.com/

These sites contain a lot of information on SharePoint development including the labs and a Virtual PC with SharePoint and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint is Microsoft's fastest growing product. It's complex to administer and develop for, and SharePoint expertise gets a pretty nice premium (at least, in the three markets I'm familiar with: Dallas, Seattle, and central Midwest). I get a few calls a week from recruiters who want my SharePoint knowledge.

If you want to be a SharePoint developer, you will need to be familiar with .NET and either C# or VB.NET, so it looks like you're covered there.

The first thing you should do is spend some quality time reading the SharePoint questions here to see what kinds of issues SharePoint developers face. There are some *excellent* SharePoint folks on SO.

Answer (score 1):

There is still plenty of SharePoint work around. However, most companies hiring SharePoint developers are looking for someone who is already an expert and will be able to help the existing .NET team learn SharePoint.

There is enough demand that you don't need a huge amount of experience to be considered an expert. However, you'll need at least some time on a real SharePoint project before you can get a job as a specialist. Your best option is probably to be working as a .NET developer for a company starting to use SharePoint or a consultancy that has both .NET and SharePoint projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to job sites such as http://www.indeed.com/ to gauge the demand for different products/technologies in your area.

A few places I have worked customized SharePoint pretty extensively.

Personally I see quite a bit of SharePoint use locally. I have gotten a few head hunting calls about SharePoint jobs recently, so there does seem to be demand here.